# Detect if user opens UIActionSheet from UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiactionsheet

As the title says. Sounds simple enough, but I haven't found any resources that teach how to do this. Pretty much, I would like to call a method every time the user brings up a `UIActionSheet` from a `UIWebView`, by tapping and holding on a hyperlink. How can I do this?

Comment: Use delegate method for that with tag.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, could you please post a more elaborate answer?

Answer (score -2):

You can do this in the delegate of your UIWebView.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{
    NSURL *requestURL = [ request URL];

    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
    {
        // Call your method here
        return NO;

    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and put an NSLog in the `if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)` statement. Upon tapping and holding on a hyperlink, the UIActionSheet shows up but the NSLog does not show in the console. I don't think this works. **Edit:** Also, the `return NO;` breaks all my hyperlinks so that they don't actually load the desired webpage. This is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: and if you put return YES ?

Comment: @samir, this is a delegate method for when UIWebView wants to go to a link, not when it does internal actions like displaying an Action Sheet. I don't know the answer to the original question, though - looking for it myself.

Comment: @AlextheUkrainian I'm still looking for an answer myself, did you have any luck in your search?

Comment: Hey @goddfree! Yeah, at least on iPhone. Haven't done much work on iPad yet, but at least on there it's in a pop-over, so you aren't blocked from adding views/doing animations while the sheet is open or is animating away. Check it out in my code here: https://github.com/substantial/choosy/blob/master/Choosy/Api/Choosy.m#L146